# Spring trying to pull snapshot from milestone repository

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-social

Trying to build https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-boot

```
gradle build --info
```

produces

```
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/social/spring-social-config/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-social-config-1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom]
```

If I just type into my browser... the resource exists at this (snapshot) url

http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/social/spring-social-config/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-social-config-1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom

Any ideas how to get gradle to go to the correct (snapshot) url?

Comment: Could you share your build.gradle?

Comment: I haven't changed it from what you see in the github url

Answer (score 5):

The snapshot repository was missing

I was initially confused between the spring-boot gradle plugin repositories and the project repositories

```
//for plugin
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    mavenLocal()
  }  
  ...

//for project
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  //added missing snapshot repository
  maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
  maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
}
```